# Displaying GeoServer WMS GetFeatureInfo in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache, getfeatureinfo, arcgis-pro

I recently set-up a GeoServer WMS endpoint with GeoWebCache.

I can get the WMS layer to display fine in ArcGis Pro 1.2.

When I click on the map to get feature information then I can see the request in Fiddler being made by ArcGis to the GeoServer.

The response contains the correct HTML but ArcGis never displays it in a pop-up.

This is not an issue in QGis.

Does anyone know why ArcGis Pro is not displaying the contents of the GetFeatureInfo response?

Comment: It could be a MIME type issue